# Intercept joystick input events

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an android IME for joysticks. It consists of a `Thread` that is constantly listening events from a specific device, and then if some conditions are true decides to do something. Is there a way to exclusively bind input events from this device to my IME, so that they won't propagate to applications?

I tried using `ioctl(fd,EVIOCGRAB,1)` inside a native library to take exclusive control of my device but it doesn't seem to work.

**Update:** `EVIOCGRAB` works fine and that's how I solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who's interested I finally found the way to do it:

use this on your "source" device (it is native code that you can use together with libEventInjector):

```
int fd = open("/dev/input/eventX", O_RDONLY);
if(fd<0) return;
if(ioctl(fd,EVIOCGRAB,1) <0) return;
```

if everything goes ok the library will have exclusive access to the device, now in your IME start a thread that keeps reading `/dev/input/eventX` so that you can read the events but they won't propagate to elsewhere.

**UPDATE:** EVIOCGRAB gives exclusive control only to an instance of a function of your Java class. The best way to intercept events without blocking the device when you close your program is this:

```
public class Class extends Thread{
    boolean running = true;
    public void run(){
        mySourceDevice.getExclControl();
        while(running){
        }
        mySourceDevice.releaseExclControl();
    }
    public void interrupt(){
        runing=false;
        super.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very interested in this. I'm not sure what you mean by "gives control to an instance of a function". How do you specify which function. Also, what is getExclControl. Is that your own method which calls the ioctl... block of code above? I assume that's C code. Could you give more detail?  Perhaps full java and c source files? Many thanks.

Comment: By "gives control to an instance of a function" I mean that if you call that function inside a method, only that method has control of your device, not the entire class. So you should be sure of doing everything you need inside such method and, finally, release the control. The code in the first block is C and it's from native library. The EVIOCGRAB 1 means require exclusive control, and EVIOCGRAB 0 means release control.